# Multiply each matrix in a list of matrices with a unique scalar found in a vector

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a numpy array list of matrices, i.e a "3d matrix" if that exists.

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
print(x[:,:,None]*x[:,None,:])

[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 2  4  6]
  [ 3  6  9]]

 [[16 20 24]
  [20 25 30]
  [24 30 36]]

 [[49 56 63]
  [56 64 72]
  [63 72 81]]]
```

I want to multiply each matrix in this array with a unique scalar, but doing this:

```
scalars = np.array([1,2,3])
print(scalars*x[:,:,None]*x[:,None,:])
```

results in this

```
[[[  1   4   9]
  [  2   8  18]
  [  3  12  27]]

 [[ 16  40  72]
  [ 20  50  90]
  [ 24  60 108]]

 [[ 49 112 189]
  [ 56 128 216]
  [ 63 144 243]]]
```

i.e each column is multiplied by the value instead. How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. One should do this instead:

```
print(scalars[:,None,None]*x[:,:,None]*x[:,None,:])
```